# Why don't URL parameters display in the page URL or href? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, url-parameters

UPDATE:
The exact problem that I am experiencing is that the URL parameters are null even if I type it in myself.

My goal is to add code parameters to the redirect URL. Let me explain. I want to have a PIN for dev mode, and when the user gets the PIN correct, they redirect to a page with a parameter, letting them through. The correct code changes every minute, based on the current timestamp. If they try to go to the URL without the correct parameter or guess the pin wrong, they get redirected to another page. Right now, the URL parameter does not show up in the address bar, even if I type it in myself.

I have tried turning off the background redirect, solidifying the pin and correct parameter, and even printing the passkey. I've only gotten one error, and that is sometimes the "passkey" variable, which you will see below, goes nil for a minute.

Here is my existing Redirect Javascript code:

```
var today = new Date();
let day = today.getDate()
let mins = today.getMinutes()
let hour = today.getHours()
let url = new URL(window.location.href)
let user = url.searchParams.get("user")
let timestamp = day + hour + mins
let passkey = timestamp * 32
console.log(passkey)

if (user == passkey) {
  if (window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/" || window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/not-available/") {
    console.log(window.location.href)
    window.location.replace("../home?user=" + passkey)
  }
} else {
  if (hour > 19 && hour < 20) {
    if (screen.width < 600) {
      window.location.replace("../not-available")
    } else {
      if (window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/" || window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/not-available/") {
        console.log(window.location.href)
        window.location.replace("../home?user=" + passkey)
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (window.location.href != "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/not-available") {
      window.location.replace("../not-available")
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my existing home page Javascript code:

```
var today = new Date();
let day = today.getDate()
let mins = today.getMinutes()
let hour = today.getHours()
let url = new URL(window.location.href)
let user = url.searchParams.get("user")
let timestamp = day + hour + mins
let passkey = timestamp * 32

function devkey() {
  today = new Date();
  day = today.getDate()
  mins = today.getMinutes()
  hour = today.getHours()
  url = new URL(window.location.href)
  user = url.searchParams.get("user")
  timestamp = day + hour + mins
  passkey = timestamp * 32
  console.log(passkey)
  let pin = prompt("Please insert your dev key.", "")
  if (pin == "32") {
    window.location.replace("../home?user=" + passkey)
  }
}
```

On the click of a text button, this function is called.

Please give feedback. I'd love to improve.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with your code and it's working, I changed the URLs to https://www.google.com (for success) and https://www.bing.com (for error) and I ended up in bing. And in your website code is working too. I didn't understand the problem

**EDIT:**
I did some tests in your first function (the one who is in the website) and the user is always *null*, so when the first *if(user == passkey)* is called, it goes direct to the last else.

```
  var today = new Date();
    let day = today.getDate();
    let mins = today.getMinutes();
    let hour = today.getHours();
    let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let user = url.searchParams.get("user");
    let timestamp = day + hour + mins;
    let passkey = timestamp * 32;
    console.log("passkey:" + passkey);
    console.log("user:" + user );

     if (user == passkey) {
     if (window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/home/" || window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/not-available/") {
      console.log("first if: " + window.location.href);
      window.location.replace("../home?user=" + passkey);
    }
     } else {
     if (hour > 19 && hour < 20) {
       if (screen.width < 600) {
      window.location.replace("../not-available");
    } else {
      if (window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/home/" || window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/not-available/") {
        console.log("second if: " + window.location.href);
        window.location.replace("../home?user=" + passkey);
      }
    }
     } else {
      console.log("final else: " + window.location.href);
    }
```

[image]

And as I said in the comment, when you make the function for the user to interact with prompt, it'll work because it's not null anymore (just need to put "32" to works).

You could do something like the devkey function, the user puts the passkey and then you verify like:

```
let pin = prompt("Please insert your dev key.", "")
if (pin== passkey) {
  if (window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/home/" || window.location.href == "https://stacker.owenrtcs1051.repl.co/not-available/") {
    console.log("first if: " + window.location.href);
    window.location.replace("../home?user=" + passkey);
  }
```

Comment: For some reason, it does work when you use parameters in other sites like google, but in this website, it redirects to the page without the URL parameters. I will try this in other browsers to see if it will work. BTW what website or IDE did you use to run this code? I use replit.com.

Comment: I edit my answer, hope that it helps you !